# Concatenating a query string with multiple joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm pretty new to joins and dynamically generating them based off fields.

All of the key variables ($et_key, $ct_key, $key) are generated based off of drop-down values mapped to database column names. Example:

```
$state = $_POST['geography'];

$states = array('Alabama','Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'District Of Columbia', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts ', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi ', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming');

$key = array_search($state, $states);

    if ($key !== false) {
        $state_key = $key+1;
    }
```

Here's my full query code. What I'm mainly confused about is what to do with all of the "and" lines----the first one cannot have an "and" but the subsequent ones must, as far as I know. I'm unsure how to fix this. I haven't refactored this or anything, sorry for the ugly repetitiveness.

```
$query=("SELECT * FROM exchange");

if($et_key) {
    $query .= " INNER JOIN`exchange_type` on `exchange_type`.exchangeID = exchange.exchangeID ";
}

if($ct_key) {
    $query .= " INNER JOIN `company_type` ON `company_type`.exchangeID = exchange.exchangeID ";
}

if($key) {
    $query .= " INNER JOIN `exchange_states` on `exchange_states`.exchangeID = exchange.exchangeID ";
}

if ($et_key || $ct_key || $key) {
    $query .= " where ";
}

if($et_key) {
    $query .= " and `exchange_type`.$et_key=1 ";
}

if($ct_key) {
    $query .= " and `company_type`.$ct_key = 1 ";
}

if($key) {
    $query .= " and exchange_states`.stateID = $state_key ";
}


if (!empty($keywork)) {
    $query .= "and (exchange.`exchange-name` LIKE '%$search%' OR exchange.`description` LIKE '%$search%')";
}


echo $query;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this one:

```
if ($et_key || $ct_key || $key) {
   $query .= " where ";
}
```

to this:

```
if ($et_key || $ct_key || $key) {
   $query .= " where 1=1 ";
}
```

then, the "ands" all make sense

Comment: Perfect! I knew it'd be an easy fix, but I was stumped. Thank you!